# Why does /USER_ID/feed return an unspecified error?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Few days ago, I noticed my application stopped working. After some debugging I found there's a problem in call to `/USER_ID/feed` (including access token, of course)

I found nothing like deprecation notice or bug report about this one. I've tried the `/USER_ID/feed` connection through [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed) and it gave me the same error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Is there something I missed or is it just Facebook's problem/bug?

Comment: Do you have the `read_stream` permission attached to that `access_token`?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I have said that "my application stopped working". It was all working before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has probably been some kind of a bug, because it's everything working again without any notice.